# Java-client-api for marklogic Encryption/Decryption

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to find out how to store encypted data in a document.
I see some Server Side XQuery APIs like **xdmp:hmac-sha256**
Is there anything similar available on java-client-api for marklogic?

I appreciate any inputs on how to approach this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would think you would use any of the encryption libraries available to Java, and write your document as binary.  Does that makes sense?

See [Writing A Binary Document](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_25738) in the Java Application Developer's Guide.

Another option would be to insert the encrypted data inside an XML element or a JSON property.  Then, of course, you would write your documents as XML or JSON.

See [Writing an XML Document To The Database](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_33048) if you want to use XML.  Substitute JSONDocumentManager if you want to use JSON.